# Как оперировать числами в php, чтобы они не преобразовались в короткие записи вроде 2.711E-5?

Tags: php, int

Как оперировать числами в php, чтобы они не преобразовались в короткие записи вроде 2.711E-5 ?

Comment: Я получаю параметр через json и вставляю его в varchar db. Итог - сокращенное число

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Это всего лишь представление чиста на экране

Answer (score 0):

В `php` есть встроенная поддержка [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php)

> Начиная с `PHP 4.0.4`, `libbcmath` встроена в `PHP`. Расширение не требует внешних библиотек.

Я не думаю, что вы используете ниже версию.

```
$mul = '13472569283574235254453454';
$bc = '134234234234233453454354';

echo bcadd($bc,$mul); // 13706803517808468707907808
```

Вы так-же сможете найти другие [математические функции и расширения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.math.php)

Но они требуют установки.